# IF range doesn't return the value needed

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing one problem and I don't understand how it can be fixed. It is a simple code: if range("A1:A100") = "Product" then range("B1:B100") should have automatically 1 (this range is empty). So for example: If anyone writes in **A1 = Product** then **B1** should automatically have **1**. Else, if **Product** is deleted from **A1**, then **1** should be deleted from **B1**. My code is below:

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub product(o As Long)

If Cells(o, "A") = "Product" And Cells(o, "B") = "" Then
    Cells(o, "B") = "1"
ElseIf Cells(o, "A") = "" And Cells(o, "B") = "1" Then
    Cells(o, "B") = ""

End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim cell As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Set cell = Intersect(Range("b1:b100"), Target)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell1 In cell.Rows
        product cell1.Row
    Next cell1
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: why not use a simple `IF` worksheet function instead of VBA?   ...(I must be missing something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet's code sheet,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim trgt As Range
        For Each trgt In Intersect(Columns(1), Target, Target.Parent.UsedRange)
            Select Case LCase(trgt.Value2)
                Case "product"
                    trgt.Offset(0, 1) = 1
                Case ""
                    trgt.Offset(0, 1) = vbnullstring
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next trgt
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this is a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually just a small fix is needed:

```
Set cell = Intersect(Range("A1:B100"), Target)
```

instead of `b1:b100`. You can even consider `Range("A:B")`, if you want to leave it active for the whole column.

Comment: damn it. This was so frustrating. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why include column B at all?

Comment: @Jeeped - it gives a small bonus, e.g. if you have `Product` in `A` and `"whatever"` in `B`, if you delete `"whatever"`, then you get `1` back. But as per the question it is probably not needed.

Comment: Perhaps but without disabling events the whole routine(s) are going to try and run on top of themselves anyways. There also appear to be numerous 'logic holes' and the string comparisons are case sensitive.

Comment: @Jeeped - yup, running more than once can be a pain.